# Extracting paragraphs from web scrape

Tags: php, arrays, dom

I'm extracting content of a particular webpage by using the code below.

```
 $html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile($url); 
  $xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
  $raws = $xpath->query( '/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]|//*[@id="content"]');
        foreach ($raws as $raw) {
  echo $html->saveHtml($raw)."\n"; }
```

The result I get is in this format:

```
paragraph of text
<br>
<br>
paragraph of text
<br>
<br>
...
```

Moreover, everything is scraped as a single data. The problem I face right now is that I can't split or divide that scraped data into parts. Is there any solution for this problem? For example, I want to show paragraphs of text but add pictures instead of < br >. Can someone enlighten me on this issue?

Comment: Which page are you trying to work with?  Are you sure it's one part or that your `foreach()` loop is actually printing out a whole bunch of items but you have nothing to show they are separate?

Comment: foreach loop printing out all the content (including paragraphs and <br>). I want to remove <br> within foreach loop and add pictures instead from another loop

Comment: Without knowing what web page your working with it's difficult to help.